# how to increase the width of the slimscroll bar in jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can we increase the width of a slimScroll bar in jQuery / javascript...
Currently it is displayed only when user plays aronnd the box and goes invisible once the user is out of that box where slimScroll bar fits...

we have used the propery **"railVisible: true"**.

but the scroll bar vanishes in a while, any idea how to increase the time of stay....

Answer (score 1):

Play with the following css...it will work

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
width: 3px;//increase this value
height: 9px; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement, #doc ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment
{
display: block;
height: 0;
background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
{
background-color: #FAFAFA;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical
{
height: 50px;
background-color: #999;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal
{
width: 50px;
background-color: #999;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
```